# Why does this .htaccess not work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like this:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?id=223
```

And this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

From what I understand this should output:

```
http://domain.com/223.html
```

But its not doing anything, can someone please explain how this works and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First things first, are you sure you have mod_rewrite installed on the server (assuming ubuntu, from terminal you do `sudo a2enmod rewrite`)

Comment: Done that and restarted Apache. I have also tried this on a hosted server

Comment: Those parameters to `RewriteRule` look the wrong way around to me. You put the one you're catching first, and the one you're redirecting to second.

Answer (score 0):

Your original rule takes any file that does not include a slash and ends with ".html" at the root level (including a file called ".html") and redirects the request to a file called index.php and it takes the first part of the filename from the request (before the dot) and passes it as a query called "id."

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Since this is .htaccess you should take the slash off

You should do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

In your html itself in the links, you'll need to call filename.html.

```
<a href='/223.html'>Some page with an id of 223</a>
```

For SEO you can take the start match off

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This would make it so you could reference a file like:

```
/somedirectory/someseotitle/223.html
```

Additionally you should then create 301 redirects from all of the `id=$id` links and make them go to their intended targets with the full URL. The code below would go into the `index.php` file at the top before any `cookies` are set or `sessions` started. As an example of what you could do... I'm only guessing about table structure:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/index.php' && !empty($_GET['id']){
    if (is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $cquery = "select count(*) from table where id = $id"; 
        $count = mysqli_result(mysqli_query($cquery),0);
        if($count == 1){
            $tquery = "select title from table where id = $id";
            $result = mysqli_query($tquery);
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $title = urlencode($row['title']);

                $headerString = "Location: /$title/$id.html";

                header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
                header($headerString);

            }
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Okay so this works on my hosting account but not on my local LAMP server. I have a url like http://localhost/myfolder/index.php?id=90 and does not work

Comment: You'll need to enable the `mod_rewrite` module in your httpd.conf file. Usually the line is already there, you'll just need to uncomment it.

Comment: The php is almost identical to what I already have except for the 301 redirects. Ill try edit the httpd.conf file

Comment: Where is the httpd.conf file in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you already have in .htaccess you will need a rule for external redirection of `/index.php?id=223` to `/223.html`. This should be your complete .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:index\.php|)\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.